# htaccess redirect to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have the following htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

I want my site to be redirected to `https://www.` with HTTPS, and enforcing the `www.` subdomain,
but when I access `http://www.` (without HTTPS), it does not redirect me to `https://www` with HTTPS.

Comment: Should be `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off`

Comment: If I do that it redirects to **h t t p s : / / w w w.w w w.**

Comment: Dear @bigben you have accepted a wrong answer here! you can find out why its wrong in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052755/7580839).

Comment: Also see this "Enforce `https` and `www` in one single 301 redirect" https://helponnet.com/2021/03/23/http-to-https-and-enforce-www-in-one-301-redirect-on-htaccess/

Answer (score 667, accepted):

To first force HTTPS, you must check the correct environment variable `%{HTTPS} off`, but your rule above then prepends the `www.` Since you have a second rule to enforce `www.`, don't use it in the first rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

#### About proxying

When behind some forms of proxying, whereby the client is connecting via HTTPS to a proxy, load balancer, Passenger application, etc., the `%{HTTPS}` variable may never be `on` and cause a rewrite loop. This is because your application is actually receiving plain HTTP traffic even though the client and the proxy/load balancer are using HTTPS. In these cases, check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header instead of the `%{HTTPS}` variable. [This answer shows the appropriate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620670/apache-httpx-forwarded-proto-in-htaccess-is-causing-redirect-loop-in-dev-envir)

Answer (score 155):

Michals answer worked for me, albeit with one small modification:

**Problem:**

when you have a ***single site security certificate***, a browser that tries to access your page without https:// www. (or whichever domain your certificate covers) will display an ugly red warning screen *before* it even gets to receive the redirect to the safe and correct https page.

**Solution**

First use the redirect to the www (or whichever domain is covered by your certificate) and only then do the https redirect. This will ensure that your users are not confronted with any error because your browser sees a certificate that doesn't cover the current url.

```
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 101):

If you are using CloudFlare or a similar CDN you will get an infinite loop error with the %{HTTPS} solutions provided here. If you're a CloudFlare user you'll need to use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 69):

### Bad solution and why

Don't ever use the solution below because when you are using their code that is something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The browser goes to:

```
http://example.com
```

Then redirects to:

```
https://example.com
```

Then redirects to:

```
https://www.example.com
```

This is too much **request** to the server.

Most of the answers even accepted one has this problem.

---

### Best solution

This code has an `[OR]` condition to prevent dual changes at url!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "BAD SOLUTION AND WHY!" - Those rules are just in the wrong order. Reverse those two rules and it will be correct - you'll get just one redirect and not two.

Comment: Yes, the code as given results in 2 redirects - I'm not disputing that - all I'm saying is that you simply need to reverse these rules to resolve this problem, no other change is required. (The "accepted" answer is indeed incorrect - which appears to be what you are referring to - the directives are in the wrong order.)

Comment: yup @AmirForsati is right. it is redirecting twice and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You can use this if you want to keep the domainname variable:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: This is redirecting me to `wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/` and then so on. How can I fix this?

Edit: Looks like I need to put it at the top of `.htaccess`. Thanks for the script :)

Comment: The first solution is not necessarily "bad" and is actually the _correct_ solution if you are implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). In this scenario you need to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS _on the same host_ first, before canonicalising the hostname (ie. redirecting non-www to www). You cannot avoid the potential double redirect when implementing HSTS, but this is only an edge case and only occurs on the user's very first visit (before the HSTS credentials have been saved).

Comment: This code gives me too many redirects error when somebody tries to access the site with www. Any idea why?

Answer (score 40):

This is the best way I found for Proxy and not proxy users

```
RewriteEngine On

### START WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
```

Comment: Correct   **This is the best way I found for Proxy and not proxy users** +1

Comment: This is the best one, as it solves multiple 301 redirects

Comment: best solution ever.

Comment: Great answer. This is the only one that worked for me. Works if you are behind Cloudflare (though I have no page rules set up at Cloudflare).

Comment: The only solution that works on all my cases.
But what if I want to do de oposite and remove all "www."

Answer (score 28):

There are a lot of solutions out there. Here is a link to the apache wiki which deals with this issue directly.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Answer (score 12):

To redirect **http://** or **https://** to **https://www** you can use the following rule on all versions of apache :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

**Apache 2.4**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Note that The %{REQUEST_SCHEME} variable is available for use since apache **2.4** .

Answer (score 8):

If you are on CloudFlare, make sure you use something like this.

```
# BEGIN SSL Redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END SSL Redirect
```

This will save you from the redirect loop and will redirect your site to SSL safely.

P.S. It is a good idea to if check the mod_rewrite.c!

Comment: it does not redirect https : // theurlwithoutwww.com to https : // www.

Comment: This is actually only working solution if you have some "add www" directives beforehand. Others solutions gives me "to many redirects".

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Notes: Make sure you have done the following steps

> 1. sudo a2enmod rewrite
> 2. sudo service apache2 restart
> 3. Add Following in your vhost file, located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Now your .htaccess will 
work and your site will redirect to http:// to https://www**

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Amir Forsati's solution [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www/43052755#43052755) but for variable domain name, I suggest:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code from this website, it works great https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I try first answer and it doesnt work...
This work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```