# .htaccess redirect to "https://www"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, web

I'm looking for an .htaccess configuration that will redirect all requests to my site to `https://www`.

So whether the user visits:

```
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

They will always end up at:

```
https://www.example.com
```

Here is what I am currently using in my .htaccess file, however it doesn't redirect if a user visits:

```
www.example.com
```

Here is my current file contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tried various solutions available on Stack Overflow, but none of them seem to work as intended, often leading to redirect loops. Hopefully someone will have a better understanding of this than I do.

Comment: Take a look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading through this now, but I feel like I'm getting lost... There is a lot of information there to sort through.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression `^example\.com` doesn't match `www.example.com`. You probably want something like `(^|\.)example\.com` or `(^|\.)example\.com($|:)`.

**Edit**:

To prevent the redirect loop add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Before the RewriteRule.

Also see http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS (they use `!=on` instead of `off`) and http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: Both of those solutions cause a redirect loop :(

Comment: @user1961626 Add "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off" before the RewriteRule.

Comment: I've tried adding that line, it's working better now but still getting redirect loops. I may have to clear my DNS cache, I'll report back after I try a few more things.