# Redirect all www and http to naked https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

htaccess rewrite rules make no sense to me! I'm simply trying to redirect the following:

```
http://www.domain.com
https://www.domain.com
http://domain.com
```

to

`https://domain.com`

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237805/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www?rq=1

Comment: Those both want to redirect to www. I want to redirect to the naked url.

Comment: It should be extremely easy to figure out how to do the inverse.

Comment: lol then why not do so and post an answer? One of the posts you're linking to doesn't even have an accepted answer...

Comment: I'm not posting an answer because you didn't do the basic effort to find a solution. The "related" sidebar on your post shows a bunch of similar questions you could consult. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I know I'm not the asker, but I tried that, it doesn't redirect `https://www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com`

Comment: This rule definitely does that if used at right place. There should not be any rule before this.