# phpmyadmin redirect to https (only for phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, apache, redirect, phpmyadmin, virtualhost

I want to set my server so it redirects `http` to `https` for `phpmyadmin` but only for `phpmyadmin`.

Basically what I want is when I type `localhost` in address bar to be `http://localhost/` but when I type `localhost/pma` (which is my phpmyadmin folder) it goes to https://localhost/pma/

I am using Apache server on Windows 10 with self signed certificate just for learning and testing stuff out.

So is it possible to do redirect with `VirtualHost` or will I have to use `mod_rewrite` to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can get a proper certificate from [lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) - stay protected! :)

Comment: 1. it makes absolutely no sense to use https in combination with `localhost` and 2. it is impossible to get a https certificate for that hostname.

Comment: Thanks. It's all just for testing purposes. :)

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection

Answer (score -2):

You could use mod_rewrite to achieve this goal. (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost/phpmyadmin/$1 [R,L]
```

Another way would be setting up a secure vHost.

---

I don't see a reason why you wouldn't just run the entire project in HTTPS, though.