# Redirect not working in Apache, HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I want to redirect all of my HTTP requests to my HTTPS (SSL) protocol. Please guys this is not a duplicate. I have already tried every question found on SO which indicate such question but none of them worked. I tried everything I found on the internet but still cannot figure out what the problem is. May be somewhere something has to be enabled or something like that.

I want to redirect from my `httpd.conf` file not from `.htaccess` because this is what suggested by Apache Org. My current Redirection Rule is

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost > 
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost >
```

I am making all of these changes in my `httpd.conf` file located in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

After every change, I also restart my server with following `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` or `service httpd restart`

I also tried following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

But still when I visit my site like `www.example.com`, I am not redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

I have a VPS Server so has enough access to my machine to enable or disable something.

Comment: have you tried everything in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)? (and make sure you restart apache)

Comment: @DevDonkey Yes Sir. I already tried everything in that question. Infact I learned from that how to redirect from Http to Https

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

This working for me:

```
 # Force SSL
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```