# http to https protocol change in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     if (location.protocol != 'https:')
        {
         location.href = 'https:' + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <span class="sample">hi</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to change the protocol in url. I placed the sample.html in apache htdocs. I am hitting with http it changing to https but site cannot be reached using https. could any one provide me solution

Comment: If you want to make your site always redirect to the HTTPS version, you should do it through your server config, not JavaScript.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection

Comment: Do you use apache or nginx?

Comment: @baao apache I am using