# https redirect with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to change my domain name http://flexy.tk to https://flexy.tk and I don't know what to edit in this .htaccess file I am new so plz help in detail and I don't want to get any risk but I try I changed the last line from http to https but I don't know is it working or not so thanks in advance

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.flexy\.tk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/flexy\.tk\/" [R=301,L]
```

**before giving downgrade try to help first friend**

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apache2+automatically+redirect+to+https&atb=v52-2_a&ia=web

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http to https apache redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)

Comment: I already search on net and I know what to add but I don't know what to edit in this code

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: What does 3rd, 4th & 5thline meaning in my code can I remove that

Comment: Yes, you can remove them. They aren't useful in your case.

Comment: No bro it doesn't work I have to remove 3,4 and 5th line then it works.... Those this line is necessary