# Forwarding Ports To A Secure Apache Web Server

Tags: apache, ssl, portforwarding

When forwarding ports to a Secure Apache Web Server should you block access to the non-secure port 80? Or can you redirect (via dns or some other method), or have Apache redirect (via it's configuration), the traffic back to the secure port 443?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be acceptable to allow incoming port 80, and then in your internal server, redirect port 80 connections to SSL port:

See: [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you to be using a linux environment. You can edit the

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Add the following under Document Root:

```
Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
```

In the URL you can also a specific port say 443 -> https://mysite.example.com:443/