# HTTP to HTTPS in Apache for a specific virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have virtual host on Apache that has configurations similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    DocumentRoot "/home/doe/www/factory/public"
    <Directory "/home/doe/www/factory/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName doe.example.com
    ServerAlias qa.dev
    ServerAlias doe202.ddns.net
    ErrorLog "/home/doe/logs/doe.log"
    CustomLog "/home/doe/logs/aq-access.log" common    
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>   
    DocumentRoot "/home/doe/www/factory/public"
    <Directory "/home/doe/www/factory/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName doe.example.com
    ServerAlias qa.dev
    ServerAlias doe202.dddns.net
    ErrorLog "/home/doe/logs/doe.log"
    CustomLog "/home/doe/logs/aq-access.log" common  
    SSLEngine on        
      SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/doe.example.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/doe.exmple.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

What I need to achieve is to redirect **only** `http://doe.example.com` to `https://doe.example.com` of course with any URI attached to it.

I have tried to look for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16200545/1592845) of that question: [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection), but it will redirect **all** hosts to HTTPS.

I also tried to change `serverName` directive in port 80 virtual host, but this will prevent users that use `http` from access at all.

Comment: Put the rewrite inside the <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: @ShingLam Note that `VirtualHost *:80` contains `serverAlias` and it will give the same result. i.e all hosts will be redirected to https.

Comment: Missed the servealias.why not set up another VirtualHost *;80 for all other server alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution depends on the solution used to redirect [`www` to non `www` with hard redirect](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708) like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^doe\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://doe.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# ... the rest of .htaccess
```

In this way, only `http://doe.example.com` will be redirected to `https://doe.example.com` while other aliases will keep its protocol as it is requested.

By the way, the website is [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) project, and all .htaccess configurations of the project comes next to the configurations above.