# apache redirecting url to default port

Tags: apache, oracle-apex

I have deployed oracle apex 18.2 on apache server , i have below URL to open the apex login page.

https://dashboards.mtbc.com:8443/ords

when i put the link on browser without writing https it give below error

`This combination of host and port requires TLS.`

I want to configure the server that i just have to write `dashboards.mtbc.com`
and it should redirect to `https://dashboards.mtbc.com:8443/ords`

Comment: Yes i already have apache server on which i have deployed apex with ords

Comment: as i am expecting some configuration on existing server so i can make URL to auto redirect to default https port

Comment: i don't want to put https to make easy for user to open the url without port and https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)