# how to redirect http angular website to https behind proxy

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I have an angular website on some port(www.example.com:4300), I had set a proxy request in my http.conf(apache configuration file). Now it is opening as www.example.com.

How can i redirect this unsecured request (http://www.example.com) to secure site(http://www.example.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)

Comment: I had already tried this. not helped.