# http sub pages are not redirected to https (secure) page - how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, apache

My site is Wordpress hosted on the Apache server.
My main page http://testa.is is redirected to https://testa.is with 301 redirects and that works fine.
My pages http://testa.is/news is not redirected to https://testa.is/news - how can I fix that?

Comment: if your website is wordpress based there are many plugins for https redirect. just search. if you prefer not to install a plugin then you should modify .htaccess  file yourself : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)