# how to redirect automatically to https from a sub domain url

Tags: jsp, url, redirect, subdomain

I have created an application using JSP & deployed on a subdomain

Now issue is if we open the application on complete link with https its working but if user type only subdomain its not working.
Is there any configuration required in tomcat files

i am simply redirecting to a custom page if user hits on index.jsp

```
Working url Example:
https://abc.xyz.com
Not working url example
abc.xyz.com
```

If url is opened with https then next time it takes https automatically i think from cache

If we open the url(abc.xyz.com) on new machine its not working

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Comment: yes apache tomcat i am using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Apache servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/how-to-automatically-redirect-http-to-https-on-apache-servers)