# url redirection from http://, www, and http://www to only https://domainname.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can anyone help me with url redirecting with .htaccess file?

I want to redirect my url to one and only https://mydomain.com

If anyone types "`www`" or "`http://`" or "`http://www`" or "`https://www`", then the user should always go to https://mydomain.com

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: No-one can reach your web page with just a "www" prefix. The browser always adds the protocol (http://). In any case, this is a very basic task and there are probably dozens of examples out there. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Dear Juhana, Thanks for your reply. As I am a new user here, I cannot post more than 2 links. So I was unable to write full url.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Add your .htaccess file to the question (only the part where you have tried the redirect) and explain what happens when you try it.

Comment: My question is if anyone try to go to my site with www or http or http[://]www or https[://]www then the user should always go to https:// (i am unable to add full domain name here. my question refers to full domain)

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: here is the code that I am using. It is only redirecting with www prefix. RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two rules. In some cases there will be a double redirection tho.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

**Edit: now it will remove the www part.**

Please note that  your SSL cert does only match site.com but not www.site.com, which will cause security alerts when you access it via `https://www`, I'm not sure you can avoid that with htaccess rules.

The first rule will trigger and redirect `https:// + www` to `https:// without www`, but the alert might fire anyway. Just give it a try.

Comment: ok so you want to always redirect to templateartist.com without www, and always use https instead of http. I'll edit the above code accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It is actually working great for www and non www redirection to https but unfortunately https+www is not redirecting. I think I dont need that too. Anyway thank you so much for your help.