# How to redirect a page both to https and to the 'www' version of the site

Tags: apache, http, redirect, ssl, https

I recently installed my SSL certificate, and I'm attempting to enforce a https connection to all my pages. However, previously I also redirected all requests to the www version of the request page. When combining an http redirect to https and concurrently redirecting traffic to www, I get a looping redirect warning on browsers. Hence, how can I make .htcaccess rule (I actually just use the directory config file) that will achieve what i want: always https://'www'

Here's the current combination that I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Actually, can somebody explain fully why not to use 'www' and why use it? Stackoverflow prevented me from linking to url with 'www' in it, hence why I'm asking. Either way, I still want to redirect all my traffic to https:// or https://'www'  [I put the quotes so StackOverflow will allow me to put the www]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13977851/1473350)

Also, you can solve the WWW problem with DNS by simply pointing your naked domain to [WWWizer's free naked domain redirect service](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect)'s IP **174.129.25.170**

Comment: I had some odd results with that solution, I would get redirect loops in some browsers and nothing in others. I can't figure out why this is so hard! Facebook seems to be able to redirect everything the way I'm asking.

Comment: @user3718546 you can always do it with php if you want to make sure it works all the time, something like `if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') { header ('Location: https://www.example.com'); }`

Comment: @user3718546 extend that for www and the condition will be `if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off' || substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 3) != 'www' )`

Comment: Yuup that works. I was doing it for static site so I ended up just doing it the nginx route (my server uses both Apache and Nginx). I'd do it with PHP but I rather make my files cacheable whenever I can.