# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site with security certificate installed at www.abc.com.
I am using .htaccess to redirect it to https when a request made with just http.

```
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

What I need is, **htaccess should make an attempt to redirect only when requested with http://www.example.com or http://example.com**.

It should avoid redirecting when a request is already made with https.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: htaccess redirection is simple. What I need is it should only redirect when a request is made without https. Your link does not provide the solution for that, Mr Borr.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, I'm genuinely curious - did you google this at all before asking? There are so many articles and tutorials on this, many on this very website..

Comment: @JerryJones that link does indeed provide a solution for redirecting *when the request isn't HTTPS*, it's the first rule in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^(www\.)?on$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.abc.fr/$1 [R,L]
```

Here is answer you need use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^(www\.)?on$
```

Comment: Worked well but a little problem occured when requested with the folowing url: https://example.com
ERROR: 
"This server could not prove that it is example.com; its security certificate is from www.example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection."

Comment: It's why you need to redirect to https://www. Read again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www : when you have a single site security certificate, a browser that tries to access your page without https:// www. (or whichever domain your certificate covers) will display an ugly red warning screen before it even gets to receive the redirect to the safe and correct https page.

Comment: change then RewriteCond, i edit answer: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^(www\.)?on$`

Comment: The `%{HTTPS}` variable will **only** be either "on" or "off", there's no www ever in that variable