# How to make redirect from http to https

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, http, https

How to redirect from http to https:

```
1. redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com
2. redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
3. redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com
```

Like facebook, google?

Please help me with code in `.htaccess` or another.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: Have you tried https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Answer (score 0):

To handle all these 3 redirects in a **single rule** you can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: When i update this rewriterule it redirect successfully to https but shows error "server not found" and some time show error "The page isn't redirecting properly", but when i remove this error and enter my domain name with https:// it working fine

Comment: Yeah i have placed correct host name, I am using cloudflare flexible ssl.

Comment: For all this link 

`http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
It redirecting to https://www.example.com`


But error is " The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: Hello bro. 

I need you help again. 
How to make same rule for sub domain. 

Like 

`http://subdomain.example.com to https://subdomain.example.com`

Comment: New error, every this is working fine but one image only showing error `The page isn't redirecting properly` and other images working fine.

What to do now ??

Comment: There is no image specific rule in the answer above. You should better post a new question with more details about the URL/error and we'll attend it.

Comment: Like `https://wwww.example.com/images/logo.png` shows a error `The page isn't redirecting properly` , but `https://www.example.com , https://www.example.com/images/ and https://www.example.com/images/someimage.png` working fine

Comment: As I requested above please create a separate new question for this problem and I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

just add below to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: When i update this rewriterule it redirect successfully to https but shows error "server not found" and some time show error "The page isn't redirecting properly", but when i remove this error and enter my domain name with https:// it working fine

Comment: Above rewrite rule worked for me and it is the best way, you may have server side error or SSL error. Try in different browser or try :                           `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^yourdomain.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         https://www.yourdmain.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]`

Comment: i forget to say you, i am using cloudflare SSL

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```