# angularjs routes and https redirect

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, https, angular-ui-router

I have an angular application that uses ui-router for routing between different states. Mainly /#/ and /#/login. I am also using SSL, so I redirect http to https in my .htaccess-file.
It works when I go to test.example.com/#/ but when I go directly to test.example.com/#/login the redirect does not work.

Note that we use a subdomain.

.htaccess look like this:(stolen from [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www))

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm actually not working on my apache conf for my own project and did this myself on my login controller :     if ($location.protocol() != 'https'){
            $window.location.href = $location.absUrl().replace('http', 'https');
    }; but that's actually not sexy at all. I'd pref to see a clean apache solution so... thumbs up !

Comment: Thanks! Will try that and hope for someone to provide a "cleaner" solution :)