# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error after .htaccess modifications for https forcing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, owncloud

I've problem with modifications in an .htaccess.

The page doesn't appear and I have this message : **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Here's the modifications I've add in the .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This is an OwnCloud installation, the full .htaccess :

```
# Version: 8.1.0
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
       SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
       RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    # Add security and privacy related headers
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "none"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true
  </IfModule>

  # Add cache control for CSS and JS files
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 513M
php_value post_max_size 513M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
php_value output_buffering off
<IfModule mod_env.c>
  SetEnv htaccessWorking true
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/calendar/caldav\.php remote.php/caldav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/contacts/carddav\.php remote.php/carddav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console).* - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed Off
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 /core/templates/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /core/templates/404.php
```

I took inspiration from this topic : [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Thanks for your support,
David.

Comment: Try changing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to `RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} =80`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to send the HSTS-Header:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Then you don´t need any HTTPS-Redirect since this is automatically done by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've got too many redirect error with every founded solution. 
This has helped me:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```