# switching a page from http to https for secured payment

Tags: php, jquery, https

Using jQuery, I try to redirect to https like the following

```
webroot  = webroot.replace("http","https");
window.location.href = webroot+"/processpayment";
```

This is not working in Live but works well in Dev environment.

The other Option I tried is redirecting in the back end code (PHP). There on load of the page (processpayment/index.php) , I called the function

```
http_redirect_https();
```

The function does the following

```
function http_redirect_https(){
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");    // Optional.
    header("Location: https://{$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]}{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}");

    exit(0); // Ensure that no other code is parsed.
}
}
```

But this threw an error - Too many redirects trying to open the page.

I am stuck. can you please help?

Comment: Not all web servers will set `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]`by default.  So maybe provide some info on your setup.

Comment: The best place to do this is your webserver config, in apache this is your virtual hosts file or the htaccess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13977851/3238924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this working is by redirecting to an intermediate PHP page and then using

header("Location: "."https://".$appurl);

Answer (score 0):

you can use htaccess or vhost for the same
try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to what you have and it works perfectly fine.

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on"){
        header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        exit();
}else{
        header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING : It the page sending the visitor to the (secure) payment page is using http (instead of https) then your website is vulnerable to sslstrip**

If you manipulate payment informations then you really should consider using https everywhere and activate HSTS, otherwise your visitors are unsafe.