# Redirect www to https://www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So far I have .htaccess  file which is able to redirect correctly from (`domain.com`) to (`https://www.domain.com`) but not working if I go to `www.domain.com` and it must redirect (`www.domain.com`) to (`https://www.domain.com`)

I need (`https://www`) always before my site url

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your first 2 redirect rules with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: after replacing redirect rules, it makes my url https://www.www. looked closed but how i can remove extra www now

Comment: See updated rule and Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: yes I always want https and www with url.
let me try this.