# How to enforce https and www in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web, https

I am trying to enforce https and www for my domain but it doesn't work for all the cases.

```
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=On [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please let me know if am missing anything in my code.

Comment: You're only redirecting non-`www.` urls to `https://www.foo.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)