# Unable to redirect from http to https in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect http://www.itcontractorsuk.com/news/contracting/guides/2016/Jun/09/6-free-tools-all-contractors-should-use to https://www.itcontractorsuk.com/news/contracting/guides/2016/Jun/09/6-free-tools-all-contractors-should-use in CodeIgniter

but instead of redirecting me to the relevant https path, it redirects me to the **HTTPS version of my homepage**

No matter what I do, it won't redirect the subfolder / entire path.

My HTACCESS file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^news/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . news/index.php [L]
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: Also besides the htacess - in codeigniter application/config/config.php - make sure that the address you have in  $config['base_url'] starts with https