# On load check if its https, if not add https and reload?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, google-chrome

I send email as `https://www.callme.com/iamavailable`, now the user clicks the url from Gmail or Outlook or Mac Mail, then it opens in Google Chrome (BUG) fine but without adding `https://` (Even though the original url was with https://, Google Chrome BUG)

As a result all the function of the application, stop working even though i have following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So, can Javascript on land read if its `HTTPS` or not? if not `HTTPS`, `windows.location.href` with `HTTPS` how?

EDIT:

```
function on_load() {
  var proto = window.location.protocol;
  console.log(window.location.protocol);
  if(proto=='http:') {
    window.location.href = 'https://talk.site.com/directory';
    //alert("You have http://, please open the page with https://");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: why is this tagged with `javascript` and `google-chrome`?

Comment: Its Javascript and Google chrome related. Because .htaccess does not work, i need to resolve it via Javascript

Comment: Then why don't you fix the .htaccess configuration? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: .htaccess is not working at all, i have tried 3 different way with .htaccess but always from email when it comes to Google chrome it lose the https:// and landing on http://

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www - I tried all of them but none of them working. always even the https:// was in the email originally, but on click it land as http://

Comment: Please see EDIT. even with Javascript manually i am adding https:// again Google chrome is opening the page without https:// ???? why?

Comment: how is `function on_load()` being called? having a function is one thing, but it needs to be executed somehow

Comment: that is called via body: `<body onload="on_load();" >` , it do get executed, but starts infinite load redirect, load redirect, load redirect... loop.