# https rules for htaccess including www redirect and removal of ".html" extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currently my .htaccess looks like this and works perfect for http.
It redirects to `www.` and removes the `.html` file extension.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I have tried the .htaccess [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) but still the site in question is completely messed up. E.g `https://example.com/work` shows a 404.
Also all images that are linked in the source code with `/img/example-01.jpg` do not show.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Can you please help me with getting a .htaccess file that:
1.
Redirects to https
2.
Redirects to `www.` subdomain
3.
Removes `.html` from file extension so that `example.com/work` shows the `work.html` page.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your current .htaccess works fine, this modification should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Nope, ´https://www.example.com/work´ result in 404, same as ´https://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg´. This is the Let's Encrypt certificate. Contacted the host already. The site is super simple with static content.

Comment: Does `https://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` work if you completely remove .htaccesss?

Comment: Just checked and no, does not work. To be precise, since there is no redirect to www. with the removed .htaccess the URL ´https://example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg´ does not work.

Comment: No. But you are right for asking a 2nd time!! `https://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` does not work, **however** `www.` seems to be in place since `http://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` works without any `.htaccess` present in the directory for the site.

Comment: Well, If you want the rewrite from `http://example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` to `https://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` to return something other than 404. you first have to make `https://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` (when entered like that directly in address bar) work, which is unrelated with .htaccess

Comment: Got your point. Thank you. In touch with the host now and asking why despite having removed the `.htaccess` completely `https://www.example.com/img/desktop/1.jpg` does not work. Very good point in fact, thank you.