# Redirecting http to https via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currently I have the following in my .htaccess file for a forum site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/forums/ [L,R=301]
```

It works perfect for redirecting everything like (http)://example.com, www.example.com, (http)://www.example.com etc. to example.com/forums which is what I wanted.

I now want to have everything redirect to (https)://example.com/forums but am running into problems with existing links such as example.com/forums/stuff.

I can only get example.com to redirect to https://example.com/forums, any direct links such as example.com/forums/stuff etc. will not redirect to the https version, any ideas?

Comment: `RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 redirect rules. One rule to redirect landing page to forums page and another rule to redirect `http -> https`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect landing page to /forums/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/forums/ [L,R=301]

# redirect http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: The first redirect rule works but for some reason the second rule does not work to forward existing links like  example.com/forums to https://example.com/forums

Comment: If you have `/forums/.htaccess` then place 2nd rule in that .htaccess