# .htaccess redirect root and index.php to https root

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please help

How redirect HTTP root and index.php to HTTPS root.
Styles and Scripts are on par with index.php.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be              included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use   www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%.   {REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```