# How to redirect website to https:// not redirect to https://www

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I need to redirect on https://domain.com

if a customer enters below URL on the browser.

1. domain.com
2. www.domain.com
3. http://domain.com
4. http://www.domain.com

I am using Codeigniter framework.
Please share me, How I can manage it by changing in .htaccess.

I am using below code in .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

    RewriteBase /demo

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: share your .htaccess

Comment: You can do it with your .htaccess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, Please let me know Do I need to add below script also or not ?                                                                                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: It's related to how your site works, not the server. But I think so. Add them after the others.

Comment: As this answer solved your problem, [you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on **tick mark** on top-left of this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242) Thank you !