# Cannot redirect http to https

Tags: apache

I cannot be able to redirect my http traffic to https so my site is reachable using both http and https but I want it only to be reachable via https. My .htaccess file located in /var/apps/web/ looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have edited apache2.conf and added the below config:

```
<Directory /var/mode/cci/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My document root located in /etc/apache2/sites-available looks as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomain.co/
        DocumentRoot /var/apps/web/
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header always unset Server
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        <Directory />
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/apps/web/>
                LimitRequestBody 512000
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        TraceEnable off

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomain.co/
        DocumentRoot /var/apps/web/
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header always unset Server
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        <Directory />
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
        <Directory /var/apps/web/>
                LimitRequestBody 512000
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
         SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        TraceEnable off

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Kindly assist!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: I want to confirm whether my document root and the apache2.conf configuration files are correct?

Comment: If your htaccess file works you need just those instructions to be placed in yours.

Comment: how can i confirm that it works? the htaccess file is located in /var/apps/web folder, is this the valid location?

Comment: Well, the fastest way to ensure that htaccess work - just write some redirect (for example to '/ololo.html') and check it in your browser. Or write some incorrect directive - that must throw you an error by apache

Comment: I have managed to make .httpaccess work however none of these rules are working on my favour

Comment: Ok, .htaccess file must be in the root of docs. Don't rename the file, just make mistake in this file

Comment: still not working, the .htaccess is accessible though because if i put deny from all as first line the application throws a forbidden status.

Comment: Great! So you found that htaccess works. Then you can paste code from another answer just to be sure that http->https works. If it does - add your instructions from old htaccess.

Comment: both protocols work. can you share a proper configuration to paste on the .htaccess to direct http traffic to https?

Comment: See accepted answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www