# redirect permenant https://site.org.in to https://www.site.org.in on apache

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It redirects https://site.org.in/ I just want site.org.in to redirect to https://www.site.org.in/

Please help.

Comment: provide current .htaccess rules.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/4921471