# How to use https and http both for accept in images in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have bought https for my website. my website images showing with http://....
so when I use https in browser, it is not showing. so I want to change it in htaccess to detect that both.
No need force http or https.
need to work both as well according to users request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: No, I no need to OFF https. I want to use both

Comment: Why you put https on your server and allow http requests? Nonsense

Comment: I only want to set https to some of special pages in my site. that's the problem I want to work both

Comment: Modern browsers don't allow non-secure calls (http) on secure connections (https). So this will be a problem regardless of your .htaccess setup.

Comment: When you use relative paths for your images in HTML, the client will access the images appropriately, e.g. `http` if the page is accessed via `http`, and `https` if the page is accessed via `https`. No need for any .htaccess rules.