# Redirect to HTTPS with URI & without www

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5, https

I have the same problem as the User [in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) I basically want to redirect all http requests to https without www using `htaccess`.

I have implemented a [solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498) and it does a pretty good job.

However, it does not redirect to the corresponding URI. If I visit my website on port 80 `example.com/news` I will be redirected to `https://example.com/index.php` which is basically the root page..

I really need your help guys, I totally have no clue about htaccess..

**EDIT** This is what my mod_rewrite looks like..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Well, how do you expect us to help without you posting your current code of that dynamic configuration file?

Comment: @arkascha I updated my post.

Comment: The issue _probably_ is that you _first_ rewrite to `index.php` and _then_ make an external redirection. Try changing the order of the rules. Note that the `L` flag only terminates the _current_ walk through the rule set. It is restarted after that.

Comment: Moved the `index.php` rewrite to the end. Works perfectly now. Thank you for your help! Please make an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue probably is that you first rewrite to `index.php` and then make an external redirection. Try changing the order of the rules. Note that the `L` flag only terminates the current walk through the rule set. It is restarted after that. So *first* do the external direction to switch to the `https` protocol, *then* do the internal rewriting if that is corrected.