# Force HTTPS using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I force HTTPS on my website? I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) answer, but for some reason I get redirected to the parent directory when I visit the index page by clicking on a link (it worked fine before adding those lines of code in .htaccess). Also, when I try to visit my website using HTTP, it lets me do it. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with how a trailing or missing trailing slash is handled by a) that answer and b) your setup.

Comment: Add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question. "I get redirected to the parent directory when I visit the index page" / "when I try to visit my website using HTTP, it lets me do it" - do you get redirected or not?

Answer (score 0):

With Apache, you have several alternatives - including .htaccess.

Look here:

- https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Per the documentation, your best bet is to use a [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive inside the non-secure`VirtualHost`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is an .htaccess example, from the same link:

```
 Redirect permanent /login https://mysite.example.com/login
```

Finally, look here for additional troubleshooting tips (for example, forgetting 'NameVirtualHost *:443' to enable Named virtual hosting for port 443):

[Why might Apache ignore a virtual host with a ServerName matching the requested URL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/288284/why-might-apache-ignore-a-virtual-host-with-a-servername-matching-the-requested)

Comment: If I use `Redirect permanent /login https://mysite.example.com/login`, it gives me this error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Also, I'm using altervista.org to host my website, so I don't know where the exact files are located at.

Comment: Not sure why that article appears to suggest using `Redirect` in `.htaccess` to perform the HTTP to HTTPS redirect - that will indeed result in a redirect loop (unless the destination URL is a different server, which is unlikely)?! (Yes, `Redirect` can be used in `.htaccess`, but not for this purpose.) If you are doing this in `.htaccess` then you will _need_ to use mod_rewrite as you will _need_ to be able to check whether the current request is HTTP or already HTTPS.

Comment: @user82217 I followed the second example from [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) link, but it doesn't seem to work either. Any suggestions?