# HTTP to HTTPS redirect is working only in Chrome browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, http-status-code-301

I am using following code in .htaccess file. It's working fine only in chrome browser. I want to redirect from non www http or www http to https:// www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{www.happyvivah.in}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on a php file on your php easily.

```
if (!(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || 
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||  
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&   
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'))
{
$redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
exit();
}
```