# How do I redirect visitors to https://www.example.com (ssl starting with www) using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I want to redirect all users to https://www- version of my website (with htaccess). My problem is that the redirection doesn't work when entering only "www.example.com" in the adress-bar so the browser warns for security. But it works when entering "https://www.example.com".

Here is my code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#first two rows redirects to correct url if non-ssl (if port is not 81)
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^81$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

#last two rows correct url if non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The ssl certificates are renewed and the hosting company has helped me set the DNS-records.The PHP version is 5.6 (shared hosting).

Is there any other approach more suitable for shared hosting?

What is wrong with my code?

Thankful for your reply!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: by doing some simple research...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I then get to the dreaded page with the warning message: The page isn't redirecting properly. So this doesn't work properly :(