# htaccess file to redirect to enforce https

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

I am trying to modify my .htacess file to enforce https, but because I already have some rules, I just appear to be breaking it. Can anyone help advise me?

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|    (.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 1):

Use the RewriteEngine. This will force ssl.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You can also check this [link](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-https) out. You have a lot of other rules you might need.

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```