# htaccess combo rule of enforcing https and www together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have gone through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) where they suggested two separate rules but I want to combine both rules into one.

For my this is working (repeating same rule)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

but this won't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Is there a possibility of htaccess unable to read three conditions?

Comment: You have to join the conditions with `[OR]`.

Comment: @akond So I need to write [OR] at the end of every **RewriteCond** statement?

Comment: Not exactly. You have to join two https conditions into one via OR, and then join the result with www condition with OR.