# How to force www, SSL and trailing slash in SilverStripe 4?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

With the latest versions of SilverStripe they encourage you to [use server side rules for URL re-writing](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/7492) and not `Director::forceSSL();` and/or `Director::forceWWW();` in your `_config.php` file as it is considered unreliable.

On an Apache server this would logically seem to suggest that it should be managed via an `.htaccess` file. Unfortunately the snippets shown below can fire a rewrite independently however chaining or combining in a single file seems to skip either the www or https case.

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
### TRIMMED ROBOT/ERROR CODE ###

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn off index.php handling requests to the homepage fixes issue in apache >=2.4
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        DirectorySlash On
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/'

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    # Deny access to potentially sensitive files and folders
    RewriteRule ^vendor(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^\.env - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule silverstripe-cache(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule composer\.(json|lock) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule (error|silverstripe|debug)\.log - [F,L,NC]


    # Process through SilverStripe if no file with the requested name exists.
    # Pass through the original path as a query parameter, and retain the existing parameters.
    # Try finding framework in the vendor folder first
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* index.php

</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ### FORCE TRAILING SLASH ###
    ### Source - https://paulund.co.uk/using-htaccess-to-force-trailing-slash ###
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    ### FORCE WWW ###
    #### Modified from source https://paulund.co.uk/add-www-subdomain-to-all-urls-using-htaccess ###
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    ### FORCE SSL ###
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: A possible and well documented .htaccess based solution might be https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052755/4137738

Answer (score 1):

Our approach is to enforce www and https in the Apache virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.myexampledomain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.myexampledomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myexampledomain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.myexampledomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.myexampledomain.com
  DocumentRoot etc etc
</VirtualHost>
```

Then finally we use this module to enforce trailing slashes: https://github.com/axllent/silverstripe-trailing-slash . There is a chance of a double redirect with this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm able to use this method as I'm using a pre-configured container on a managed host. I have made use of the module for the trailing slashes now though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start with moving your rewrite rules above the SilverStripe ones - they can be last.

Secondly, the `[L]` flag on your rules means "Last" and will stop any further processing, you may want to try removing them.

Thirdly, from your code you could potentially see 2 redirects (3 requests in totla) for a URL here which (IMO) is a worse experience (thus SEO impact) than a single redirect that doesn't enforce the www and/or the trailing slash.

It looks to me like you could have the following set of redirects just to hit a page:

```
http://example.com/contact-us
http://example.com/contact-us/
https://www.example.com/contact-us/
```

The alternative is SS4 is to use a HTTPMiddleware that could enforce this for you in PHP. Whilst not recommended it could be a bit more "transportable"

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, the documentation for writing your own .htaccess isn't always that helpful. I was hoping to write a single rule that would cover all bases dynamically but didn't manage to get there.

Comment: It's not really possible or worthwhile for SilverStripe to attempt to completely document all the different aspects you may wish to achieve with RewriteRules, therefore I wouldn't rely on SilverStripe documentation as a canonical or complete reference for writing RewriteRules in .htaccess files - the apache documentation would be a much better place to look. - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: I was actually referring to .htaccess documentation I had found, not SilverStripe's docs. But the page you have linked is much better than what I had been looking at so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

We've had the same issue and added the following to the /.htaccess file (not /public/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Adding the rules to the /public/.htaccess resulted in a redirection to https://www.your-domain.com/public which caused an 404 - Page not found error.