# http to https redirect with subdomains and www conversion via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, subdomain

I need every call to a specific subdomain(s).example.com.xx add the www at the beginning and then redirect it to https.

At [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) there is a solution but does not work with sub.example.com.xx redirecting to https://www.sub.example.com.xx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If I type http://sub.example.com.., I get https://sub.example.com.xx and not https://www.sub.domain.com.xx

Even with http://yyy.sub.example.com.xx must give me https://www.yyy.sub.example.com.xx

Examples:

```
example.com.xx ---> https://www.example.com.xx
http://example.com.xx ---> https://www.example.com.xx
https://example.com.xx ---> https://www.example.com.xx

sub.example.com.xx ---> https://www.sub.example.com.xx
http://sub.example.com.xx ---> https://www.sub.example.com.xx
https://sub.example.com.xx ---> https://www.sub.example.com.xx

other.sub.example.com.xx ---> https://www.other.sub.example.com.xx
http://other.sub.example.com.xx ---> https://www.other.sub.example.com.xx
https://other.sub.example.com.xx ---> https://www.other.sub.example.com.xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

www first, to avoid a double redirection.

Comment: I have edited my question. Your last example at least works in the case sub.example.com.xx . Thanks . I must test the other cases.