# how do I remove http to https redirects cent OS wordpress LAMP stack

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, centos

I have a website that has redirects when I moved to https. I have since removed some of those pages but the redirects are still there an giving me 404 error.

I have checked the .htaccess file and the redirects are not there. Where are these redirects kept?

the answered provided in the post is on how to make the changes in .htaccess this is not located in the .htaccess file

example 
http://website/page to https://website.page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: If it is not in the .htaccess files, it is in the global configuration files.  Start with httpd.conf.   Then review any `Include` file from httpd.conf.