# Laravel: Redirect to https://www.*** does not work in Firefox?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I added to the .htaccess file this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/2311074 to redirect my website always to `https://www.**********`. This works in Chrome, but it is not working in Firefox.

If I enter

```
https://example.com
```

then its not redirecting anywhere.

in Firefox. In Chrome they are correctly redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

I aready deleted the cache and tried to call the website from other PC's but its still not working. This is my htaccess FIle from Laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
    # the subsequent rule will catch it.
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    # [NC] is a case-insensitive match
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox's private mode?

Comment: @Karolis yes in private mode and on other pcs (windows 7 and ubuntu). The redirect is still happening, the url is coaching-institutes.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I only had a SSL certificate for the domain ***www.example.org*** but not a SSL certificate for the domain ***example.org***. Thus the url ***https://example.org*** is invalid, was not loaded and could not be redirected with the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score -2):

See comments below for the answer to question.

Comment: So you are saying that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www/13997498#13997498 does not work in firefox?

Comment: Make sure you have the SSL installed for not just https but also www as well.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ig267b Domain working for me in firefox, you must have incorrectly installed cert for https

Comment: I only have the SSL installed for `https://www.***` this is why I wanted the redirect to the www page in the first place

Comment: is the domain working for you if you enter `https://coaching-institutes.net` in your browser? I tried it also on other PC's and it was not working

Comment: Your website is configured incorrectly. I would suggest reinstalling your SSL cert for that domain. coaching-institutes.net uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: www.nlp-institutes.net, www.coaching-institutes.net, www.world-hypnosis.org

Comment: SSL certificate is only setup for `www.coaching-institutes.net` and not for `coaching-instiutes.net`. Thats why I want a redirect to a `www.***` and I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: You do realize if you go to just `coaching-institutes.net` it redirects to the `https://` hence why i said install a cert for normal https and not just `www` and then you can implement a redirect from `https` to `https://www.`

Comment: `www.coaching-institutes.net` is working but `https://coaching-institutes.net/` is not working

Comment: Read my previous comments lmao. I have stated it several times now.

Comment: @Adam Having a www-only certificate, I would try swapping places of redirect rules, i.e. first redirect to www and then to https.

Comment: @Karolis thanks for the tip. I tried it, but its still not redirecting to www

Comment: @Adam Your website gets perfectly redirected from http to https, and from non-www to www. It's clearly the problem of rule ordering. Clear the cache or reopen a new private window for testing after every change in htaccess file.

Comment: @Karolis are you sure? I cleared cache & restarded my pc but if I enter `https://coaching-institutes.net` there is no redirect happening see [https://image.ibb.co/isECi7/Bildschirmfoto_vom_2018_02_17_18_06_59.png](https://image.ibb.co/isECi7/Bildschirmfoto_vom_2018_02_17_18_06_59.png). I also tried it on 2 other computers and no redirect happend there aswell, so I am very surprised that you say it works on your PC. Are you sure?

Comment: @Karolis I have a new idea: Maybe the .htaccess is not even executed in Firefox, because I have no certificate for the `https://coaching-institutes.net` and thus its not redirected? But strange that it works in Chrome..

Comment: @Adam Yes I was sure, I meant the rules worked fine *separately*. As for `https://coaching-institutes.net` (i.e. https+non-www), you're absolutely right, this will never get redirected anywhere because you don't have a certificate for it. But http+www and https+non-www may get easily redirected to https+www with the *correct rule ordering*. Just don't promote https+non-www version anywhere on the web and nobody will use it because nobody types protocol names (i.e. `https://`) in the address bar by hand.

Comment: The answer is legit what i said like 300 times, wtf. http://prntscr.com/igd584 http://prntscr.com/igd5a7