# Redirecting second level domain to a third level, but only if in root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**WHAT I HAVE**

Thanks to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/1399706) I've solved the problem of the "always https" redirect using this in my `.htaccess`:

```
# Redirect to httpS by default
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to www if third level domain is not set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**WHAT I WANT**

As per the current configuration, `https://example.com` is correctly redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

BUT I need that if the URL contains `wp-admin` it isn't redirected to `www`.

So, for example, `https://example.com/wp-admin` hasn't to be redirected.
And also every subpage of the path `wp-admin` hasn't to be redirected.

`https://example.com/wp-admin/login.php` has to be visible without redirecting to `www` but from the second level domain.

**CONTEXT** (if you are curious about why I need this configuration)

I have the domain `example.com`.

This domain has some third level domains and has a Wordpress admin area at `example.com` (second level):

- `example.com`
- `www.example.com`
- `help.example.com`
- `another.example.com`

But

- `www.example.com` is a Symfony app that runs on Heroku;
- `example.com` is a Wordpress multisite installation that runs on DigitalOcean;
- `help.example.com` and `another.example.com` are Wordpress sites handled with the multisite of `example.com`

For these reasons I need to redirect the second level domain to `www` if in the path there isn't `wp-admin`. In all other cases I need the redirect to `www`.

Comment: you want to force them into https with www then ecxlude example.com/wp-admin only from being with www but still https , right? what about example.com/wp-admin without www ? do you want also to change it without www?

Comment: I always want to force the use of `https`. Then I want to access `https://example.com/wp-admin` but want to redirect root `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` because it is the main app. I've updated the question hoping it is now more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You want redirect "http to https" ?
put this in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thank you, I found the same exact solution! Anyway thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was as simple as adding a second `RewriteCond`.

The complete `.htaccess` is this:

```
# Aerendir - Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# First rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Then redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```