# Redirect all traffic to https AND www - currently only working on main domain, not subpages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all traffic to both https and www on a WordPress site. I have gone through dozens of stackoverflow posts and feel like I finally found the answer here: [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www#answer-13997498)

I am using the code below in my htaccess file and it's somewhat working. The root domain inspiresoftware.com is redirecting to https://www.inspiresoftware.com. However if I go directly to a subpage ex. inspiresoftware.com/library, it redirects to the www version, but not the https version. What do I need to edit to make it do both? Thanks!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /q
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I assume you got the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997498/1526322 -- Did you see the section about proxying? Does that apply to you?

Comment: @Knox unfortunately, not. Thanks for the help though!