# How to redirect all non-www to www and SSL Url in Opencart journal theme?

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

The problems are like

1. When I use `http://www.example.com` : It works fine.
2. When I use `https://www.example.com` : It works fine with my www ssl certificate
3. When I use `http://example.com` : I lose my styles and icons.
4. When I use `https://example.com` : I lose my styles and icons.

Now I want it in these ways :

1. When I use `http://example.com` : It should redirect to `https://www.example.com`
2. When I use `http://www.example.com` : It should redirect to `https://www.example.com`.
3. When I use only `example.com` : It should redirect to `https://www.example.com`

Here is my current `.htaccess.txt`

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please direct me how I can achieve what I want and how to fix styles and icons problem. Thanks in Advance !

Comment: This would be better done at the `httpd-vhosts.conf` level if you can. Configure separate `<VirtualHost>` directives for the domain with **and** without the *www*, with the "base" `<VirtualHost>` just having something like `Redirect * https://www.example.com` in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code inside `htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```