# How to add www in front of sub-domain created dynamically?

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I want to add www in front of the sub-domain which was created dynamically. 
The subdomain was created using *.example.com in the cpanel, so that user can create their own sub-domain through front-end.

I have added this code in .htaccess to direct my domain to https://www.example.com. But this doesn't work with subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How do I rewrite the code so that when using www.subdomain.example.com it can directs to subdomain.example.com? Without affecting my main domain name. My main domain and sub domain both will have www redirect.

Comment: do you want to remove www from sub domain and force https as well ?

Comment: @Mohammed Elhag I want to enable www in front of subdomain. The user can use either www.subdomain.example.com or subdomain.example.com to view the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression to match the subdomain, and use **RewriteCond backreference** to redirect back the users:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`[^\.]+` matches one or more characters except dot (`.`) character. `%1` is **RewriteCond backreference** that provide access to the grouped part `([^\.]+)`.

Comment: Will this affect the main domain? Sorry, I don't have much knowledge on .htaccess

Comment: I just need to add this code below my existing code? My main domain and subdomain, both need to enable www in front of them.

Comment: can you clarify your question what is the expected result for your main domain and subdomain, and give example.

Comment: The user can use www.subdomain.example.com to view subdomain.example.com, and www.example.com to view example.com.

Comment: The current .htaccess allow the www.example.com direct to example.com, but not allow www.subdomain.example.com to direct to subdomain.example.com. I want the main domain and sub-domain can direct to their destination with www.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it.

Comment: I get the result by adding this few code under the existing code. Thanks.