# TYPO3 - HTTPS Migration

Tags: https, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm running a website under TYPO3 6.2 and follow [this tutorial](http://www.nitsan.in/blog/post/the-unconventional-guide-converting-your-typo3-site-from-http-to-https-ssl/) in order to migrate my website on HTTPS. For now I got success with :

- following typoscript configuration on the root page :

> ```
> config.absRefPrefix = auto
> config.baseURL >
> ```

- following TSconfig on the root page :

> `TCAdefaults.pages.url_scheme = 2`

.. and everything seem to work fine. But if I edit this parameter :

[image]

... website shuts down with infinite redirection loop (301 Moved Permanently). Why ? The result is the same (infinite loop) if I execute this query :

```
UPDATE pages SET url_scheme = 2
```

...and same for BE if I make this change :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['lockSSL'] = ‘2’;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `url_scheme` field exactly because of issues like these. In fact this field was [dropped with TYPO3v8](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79302-MovedPagesurlSchemeToCompatibility7Extension.html). Any Page TSConfig related to `url_scheme` should be removed and you should run an SQL query to fix all existing pages.

Instead you should [enforce HTTPS using a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) in your `.htaccess`.

Infinite loops like these are usually caused by redirects performed both by TYPO3 and your webserver:

1. You request the site with HTTP.
2. TYPO3 redirects to HTTPS
3. Your webserver redirects to HTTP
4. Repeat 2. and 3.

For this reason you should also check your existing redirects, e.g. for enforcing `www.` in your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I removed all my previous changes and only made redirection via .htaccess. It works fine ! Except for the backend with a new loop on /typo3/... So, do I have to change other parameters or .htaccess rewriterule is enough ?

Comment: If i set "lockSSL" to 2 -> infinite loop. If set to "0", backend interface loads but I get "Connection Problem
Sorry, but an error occurred while connecting to the server. Please check your network connection." and impossible to make any click.

Comment: You don't need any configuration in TYPO3 if you redirect all requests to HTTPS. As for the last error please retry after flushing browser caches or in a different browser.

Comment: Problem is still here. In the Chrome console i got multiple errors like : "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/typo3/backend.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/typo3/ajax.php?ajaxID=ExtDirect::route&namespace=TYPO3.Components.PageTree'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."