# Redirect Any Domain from non-www to www and to HTTPS without double redirect

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

to redirect from non-www to www

[On this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) I found the following code, to make such redirection, and also http to https redirect, without casuing a double redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I don't want the `example.com` part, I need a flexible code.
So I tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

something in syntax is bad, and it doens't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, seems to work. can't delete chrome cache though from previous experiments, so some url just won't load. clearing website data for the site doesn't work either.

Comment: You can try with other browser

Comment: @Joe No, it's not true. The first is only if without www -> https-www and the other only if http -> https alredy with www. Never more than one redirect !

Comment: @Croises yep, fair point. I see what you mean now. I was going about this completely wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Using `%{HTTP_HOST}` will grab the host instead of implicitly calling `example.com`. Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

***EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1.%2/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: this code is casuing an extra `www` when already inputing one `www`

Comment: It shouldn't do.... do you have any other rewrites effecting it? All the same, I've made an edit to the code for you to try again.

Comment: This one is causing a redirect loop.
I didn't had more rewrites. the problem aroused when I test url with HTTPS and without WWW.

Comment: You can't do that, because no `%1` if `%{HTTPS} = off`