# order seems irrelvant for https://www redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

In the question [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) the answer was basically this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The second [higest upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509934/2311074) stated that if you only have a single certificeted domain that one should reverese the order.

In my case I only have a SSL certificate for `https://www.example.com` but not  for `https://example.com`. I am using the above `.htaccess` settings, so I have not reversed the order.

When I enter `http://example.com` I expected it to be redirected first to `https://example.com` (because of the `L` flag) and to throw a warning like

[image]

To my surprise, this gets correctly redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

Why is this not redirected to `https://example.com` and throwing a warning?

Comment: @anubhava I deleted browser cache, tried it with another browser that I never used and in inkognito mode. They all redirected as above.

Comment: @anubhava okay I checked **caching disabled** and the first request is `http://example.com` with status `301`. Next there is the `https://www.example.com` request with status `200`. There is neither a `http://www.example.com` nor a `https://example.com` request.

Comment: I suspect there is some other rule/code doing a redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` in your system