# How to redirect a website from non secure to secure site using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

How can i redirect my website i.e subdomain.domainname.com to https without www in the front and currently this is my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

by default when user visit subdomain.domainname.com to should go https

the configuration breaks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Comment: it breaks the configuration for me

Comment: add a RewriteRule like this>>:    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]