# .htaccess redirect to subdomain and enforce HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, subdomain

I'm trying to apply a set of htaccess rules.

I want to redirect all http requests to https, and all requests to use the subdomain webshop rather than www.

I had a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www) but cannot make sense of how to apply it to my case.

Currently I have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^playmobilland.dk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://webshop.playmobilland.dk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this does not route www requests to https.

How do I add a redirect to send www requests to https as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.playmobilland.dk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://webshop.playmobilland.dk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the extra line and understand the logic of ic. I'm not sure if there is some kind of server-side caching, but apparently the change doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Did you try redirecting all traffic to https (forgetting about the subdomain part, for testing purpose)? what is the result?